# how to customise UINavigation bar with two labels left aligned

Tags: swift, xcode, interface-builder, uinavigationbar, swift5

Requirement

[image: Required Design]

I am only able to bring the title at centre

how it can be done?

Comment: Hide the navigation bar and use your custom view(UIView).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom view and set it as the `titleView` of the navigationItem.

***TitleView.xib***

- Add a `UIView` and create the layout as you wish.
- Set the backgroundColor of the View and ViewController to `clear`.

[image]

***TitleView.swift***

```
import UIKit

class TitleView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
    
    class func instanceFromNib() -> TitleView {
        return UINib(nibName: "TitleView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! TitleView

    }
    
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return UIView.layoutFittingExpandedSize
    }
}
```

***ViewController.swift***

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
        
      self.navigationItem.titleView = TitleView.instanceFromNib()
 }
```

#### Preview

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Custom view, set navigationItem.titleView.